# Defining a variable in awk

Tags: awk

I have an input file thus:

```
3.59717487E+05  3.40210880E+06        4075.32   7066.00   4075.32 7066      4075.322 2 a_final_psdm_LY1-1250_20160307             
3.59725248E+05  3.40211860E+06        4063.53   7067.00   4063.53 7067      4063.527 2 a_final_psdm_LY1-1250_20160307             
3.59733009E+05  3.40212840E+06        4051.73   7068.00   4051.73 7068      4051.731 2 a_final_psdm_LY1-1250_20160307             
3.59740771E+05  3.40213820E+06        4039.94   7069.00   4039.94 7069      4039.936 2 a_final_psdm_LY1-1250_20160307
```

I need to get the last column and define a variable that is just the LY1-1250 part. This is what I have so far:

```
awk ' 
BEGIN{

     if($NF !~ /LY1/){
       print
     }
     else{

        tag=$NF
        print tag
     }
 }
```

but this gives me tag=a_final_psdm_LY1-1250_20160307

I need tag=LY1-1250

In a shell script I would just do

> tag=`echo $NF | sed ... blah blah

but within awk it doesn't seem to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this:

```
awk '
{
   if(!match($NF,"LY1[^_]*")){
     print
   }
   else {
     tag=substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH)
     print tag
   }
}' input.file
```

`match()` finds the regular expression.

This function is also setting two special variables `RSTART`and `RLENGTH` that indicate where the regular expression begins and ends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really need to have the value defined as a variable as it will be used further down the script.

Comment: @jaffa1201 the `tag` variable had been added, see the updated answer.

Comment: That works perfectly! Is it possible to have it take 8 characters starting from the letter L, rather than defining the starting character? the string may be defferent lengths elsewhere in the file (this is why i wanted to use sed). Thanks mate.

Comment: @jaffa1201 the `RLENGTH` had been replaced with `8` in the answer. I understand it should met your last requirement

Comment: it is the RSTART that i would like to change to match a string; say LY1.

Comment: @jaffa1201 I do not get this last one. `RSTART` is set by the `match()` to the index of `LY1[^_]*`. `RLENGTH` is the associated length. The regex matches LY1 followed by any number of chars (different lengths) until the next `_` char.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "tag" is the part after the penultimate `_`, you can simply use that as a field separator:

```
$ awk -F_ '{if($(NF-1)~/LY1/){print $(NF-1)}else{print}}' file
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
```

Or, to use it as a variable:

```
awk -F_ '{if($(NF-1)~/LY1/){tag=$(NF-1); print tag}else{print}}' file
```

I don't understand why you had your code in a `BEGIN{}` block, that would only have been run once and before any lines were read, so `NF` wouldn't even be defined.

Anyway, for the general case, the way to save a substring in a variable in awk is to use `substr` or `sub`. So, you could also have done something like:

```
$ awk '{ 
        if($NF~/LY1/){
            tag=$NF; 
            sub(/.*LY1/,"LY1",tag); 
            sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",tag); 
            print tag
        }
        else{ print } }' file
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
LY1-1250
```

Comment: Clever trick, but may I ask why you put the conditions inside the code block, rather than in from of it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the conditionals of `awk`. The beginning of each line *is* the condition. This is a more... `awk`-ward way to do it: What about

```
awk '
/LY1/ { 
        tag=gensub(/_.*/,"","1",gensub(/.*LY1/,"LY1","1", $NF))
        print tag
        next
}
{
    print
}' input.file
```

The first `/LY1/` is an implicit `matches`-condition - it only executes the expression if the input line matches that regular expression. The expression starts with substituting everything on that line, up to, and including, `LY1` with `LY1`, and puts that in variable tag. It then prints tag, and the `next`-statement skips all other expressions *for this record*.

After that comes an unconditional expression, that just prints the line as it is - but this won't be executed if the prior expression was executed, since that would have called `next`.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want except that it prints the characters after the section i want as well. i.e.  LY1-1250_20160307. Can I limit the number of characters it prints?

Comment: Sure, updated the answer to fix that. May I ask what `awk` you are using? `gawk`, `nawk`, or something else?